# Pohlig-Hellman algorithm

Tags: algorithms, modular-arithmetic, prime-factorization

I'm trying to use the Pohlig-Hellman algorithm to solve for $x$ where $15^x=131(\bmod 337)$.  This is what I have so far:

prime factors of p-1: $336=2^4*3*7$

$q=2: x=2^0*x_0+2^1*x_1+2^2*x_2+2^3*x_3$

$x_0$: $131^{168}=15^{168*x_0}$, $-1(\bmod 337) = (-1)^{x_0}(\bmod 337)$, $x_0=1$

$x_1:$ $131*15^{-(1)}=131*45=166(\bmod 337)$, $166^{184}=15^{168*x_1}$, $148(\bmod 337)=-1^{x_1}(\bmod 337)$

However, from there, $x_1$ has no answer.  So I know I've done something wrong, I just don't see what.  I've double and triple checked every computation, so I assume I misunderstand something about the algorithm.